# Regular Expression With String Contain Digit With WildCard/Min,MaxLength In Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am new to JavaScript Regular Expressions. Currently I am trying to create a regex on a String that may contain a digit.

Scenario is like following:<

The String may contain a `*` either before or after or both but not in the middle.

The String length will be a minimum of 2 characters and a maximum of 12 characters (not counting the `*`).

Input String Example:

```
AB1542378522
AC6546457869
OA6546457869
```

Other valid Strings are:

```
*154*
*C6*
AB*
AB154237*
*2378522
*C654645
*645
*AB*
*AC6546457869*
OA*
```

Invalid Strings:

```
*15*4
*15*4*
*A*B15*42*37*
```

Only the `*` wildcard is supported, no other special character allowed in input. For example in above input string `AB`, `AC` and `OA` are valid first two character but not `AA`, `AX`, `OS`... then it will follow 10 digits at max.

I am unable to create such regex that covers above use-cases. My code is getting exhausted by if else branching. If I find any answer I will post it in a comment. Make a comment for any confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this pattern:

```
/^\*?(?=[^*]{2})[A-Z]{0,2}[0-9]{0,10}\*?$/
```

pattern explanation:

```
^           begining of the string
\*?         optional * 
(?=[^*]{2}) check if at least 2 characters that are not * follows
[A-Z]{0,2}  between zero and 2 letters
[0-9]{0,10} between zero and 10 digits
\*?         optional *
$           end of the string
```

Comment: the lookaheads, +1. Didnt think of that in mine

Comment: thanks Casimir et Hippolyte,it works like a charm.also underlying explanation is good enough to make some changes according to my needs.currently i'm reading Javascript bible for regex,tutorial is quite good but would you like prefer me any book or tutorial for regex?thanks.

Comment: @RawAliasCoder: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good site to learn point by point the different features of regex.